# Boolean logic misunderstanding

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a problem here. In the beginning of my game it asks "Ready" and if you click it, it will reset everything just in case the game glitched out and it would play the appropriate level that the user selected in the beginning of the game (main menu). I tried to make booleans for each level so I could tell what level he or she is playing this is what I tried and received no luck.

```
var playingLevel1 = false;
var playingLevel2 = false;
$('#level1Button').click(function() {
  playingLevel1 = true;
});
$('#level2Button').click(function() {
  playingLevel2 = true;
});
$('#ready').click(function() {
  if(playingLvl2) {
    startLvl1(); //and that would reset and start the level one
  }
  if(playingLvl2) {
    startLvl2(); //and that would reset and start the level two
  }
});
```

You would think that would work? But it doesn't. I don't think I'm using booleans right maybe?

I just typed up that sample code but it's pretty identical to what my original code is like.

Ok so I decided to use an integer but that still wont work here is what i got

```
var currentLevel = 0;
    $('#level1').click(function () {
        currentLevel = 1;
        $("#mainMenu").hide();
        levelOne();
    });
    $('#level2').click(function () {
        currentLevel = 2;
        $("#mainMenu").hide();
        levelTwo();
    });

   function startLvl1() {
        $("#levelOne").css('margin-top', '-1520px');
        $("#player").css('border', 'solid 1px green');
        $("#player").css('margin-left', '223px');
        $('#levelComplete').hide();
        $('#levelOne').animate({
            'margin-top': '+=1520px'
        }, speed);
        handleCollisions();
    }
     function startLvl2() {
        $("#levelOne").css('margin-top', '-4560px');
        $("#player").css('border', 'solid 1px green');
        $("#player").css('margin-left', '223px');
        $('#levelComplete').hide();
        $('#levelOne').animate({
            'margin-top': '+=4560px'
        }, speed);
        handleCollisions();
    }
    $('#yes').click(function () {
        if (currentLevel == 1) {    
                startLvl1();
        }else if (currentLevel == 2) {
         startLvl2();   
        }
```

Comment: The first conditional "if" in `$('#ready').click` should be `if(playingLvl1)` and you have `if(playingLvl2)`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using Boolean, consider storing integer of the level number.

```
var currentLevel = 0;

$('#level1Button').click(function() {
  currentLevel = 1;
});
$('#level2Button').click(function() {
  currentLevel = 2;
});

$('#ready').click(function() {
  if (currentLevel == 1)
    startLvl1();
  else if (currentLevel == 2)
    startLvl2();
});
```

This should be the right way! `:)`

Comment: Oh wow never thought of that, thanks a lot I'll try it right now!

Comment: Sure @KarinaAyoub. Let us know if you face any difficulties. `:)`

Comment: @KarinaAyoub What do you wanna achieve?

Comment: @KarinaAyoub In your code, the first `if` condition is wrong. It should be `if (playingLvl1)`.

Comment: Updated the code still does not work im using integers now what is wrong now jeez this is frustrating I can never get booleans or If statements actually working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65404/discussion-between-karina-ayoub-and-praveen-kumar).

Answer (score 0):

The boolean variables are misspelled?  I.e., 'playingLevel1' is the variable defined, but your if statement has 'playingLvl1'.  So, since that variable is not defined, it is always false.  Same goes for 'playingLevel2'.